# How to make data to trigger after a fixed period in Dataflow?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a streaming dataflow job which reads data from PubSub with intrinsic timestamp. The data has to be accumulated for 30 minutes(based on event time) and then triggered down the pipeline. Below is my code snippet,

```
PCollection<String> pubsubData =
p.apply(PubsubIO.Read.timestampLabel(TIMESTAMP_ATTRIBUTE).topic(options.getTopic()));

pubsubData
 .apply(ParDo.named("ParseAction").of(new ParseEventFn()))
 .apply(Window.named("ActionWindow")
     .<Data>into(FixedWindows.of(
         HALF_HOUR))
     .triggering(
       AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
       .withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
             .plusDelayOf(ONE_MINUTE))
       .withLateFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
             .plusDelayOf(ONE_MINUTE)))
     .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(options.getAllowedLateness()))
     .discardingFiredPanes())
 .apply("ProcessData", new ProcessData());
```

With the above code, the data reaches ProcessData class before completion of 30 minutes of event time. If I use below code without trigger, the data does not reach the class ProcessData even after 30 minutes.

```
pubsubData
.apply(ParDo.named("ParseDayUserAction").of(new ParseEventFn("day")))
.apply(Window.named("UserActionDayWindow").    
<ActionData>into(FixedWindows.of(HALF_HOUR))
  .discardingFiredPanes())
.apply("ProcessData", new ProcessData());
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: To clarify, are you expecting the first snippet to fire before 30 minutes of event time, or does that not match your expectations?

Comment: @Sam My requirement is to make the data available to below pipelines (ProcessData) only after 30 minutes of event time.

Comment: can you help me understand the presence of early firings in the first code snippet, if the intention is to only process data after 30 minutes of event time?  These will cause the trigger to fire one minute after it sees the first element.

Comment: @Sam Thats right, the code is firing after one minute. Please ignore it. I provided that snippet to show that only If I provide some trigger statement, I am getting data out of the window else I am not getting data to ProcessData ParDo function. Is my second snippet correct for my usecase?

Comment: Yes, that snippet is correct, though the .discardingFiredPanes should be unnecessary.